finding cardinality of binary sequences of length $10$ that do not contain two consecutive zeros
We have $A=\{(a_1,a_2\ldots a_{10})\in\{0,1\}^{10}|~a_i~\text{and} ~a_{i+1} \text{ are not 0 for any }1\leq i\leq 10\}\}.$
What I see is that the cardinality of $A$ can be found using Fibonacci sequence by setting a bijection. I want to know alternatives to this approach without even having an idea about Fibonacci.
Define
$$A_{n}=\{(a_1,a_2\ldots a_{n})\in\{0,1\}^{10}|~a_i~\text{and} ~a_{i+1} \text{ are not 0 for any }1\leq i\leq n-1\}\}.$$
Then $A_{n}=A_{n'}+A_{n''}$, where $A_{n'}\subset A_{n}$ and $A_{n''}\subset A_{n}$
$A_{n'}={ (a_1,a_2\ldots a_{n-1},0)}$ and $A_{n''}={ (a_1,a_2\ldots a_{n-1},1)}$, then we have bijections $A_{n'}\to A_{n-1}$ and $A_{n''}\to A_{n-2}$.  To find $|A_{10}|$, I have $|A_{10}|=|A_9|+|A_8|$. And finally the Fibonacci sequence tells me $144$ is the answer.

The set of all binary sequences with no two zeroes in a row?

yes it is , you read it........

The way your question was written, it was not clear. Anyway, include your attempt, and maybe the solution you know about.

ok added solution  but downvoting will force me to delete this post

Here is a somewhat different approach. At first we reformulate the task a bit. We take a binary alphabet $\mathcal{V}=\{0,1\}$ and count the number $A_n$ of strings of length $n$ built from this alphabet which have no consecutive zeros. We are interested in $A_{10}$.
We use a generating function approach and start with a generating function for binary words which have no consecutive equal letters $0$ or $1$ at all. Words with no consecutive equal letters are called Smirnov words. A generating function for a two-letter alphabet of Smirnov words is
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{S(z;a,b)=\left(1-\frac{az}{1+az}-\frac{bz}{1+bz}\right)^{-1}}\tag{1}
\end{align*}
where the parameter $a$ indicates an occurrence of $0$ and $b$ an occurrence of $1$. Some more information about Smirnov words can be found in example III.24 in Analytic Combinatorics by R. Sedgewick and P. Flajolet.
We derive a generating function for the number $A_n$ of valid strings of length $n$ by using a proper substitution in (1). Since there is no restriction given to the occurrences of $1$, we find all valid strings by replacing occurrences of $1$ by one or more $1$s. In terms of the generating function this can be written as
\begin{align*}
bz \to bz + (bz)^2+(bz)^3+\cdots=\frac{bz}{1-bz}
\end{align*}
Since no consecutive equal digits of $0$ are allowed, which is already given by the generating function (1) for Smirnov words, we use $az$ in (1) without any change. The generating function $A(z;a,b)$ we are looking for is therefore given as
\begin{align*}
{\color{blue}{A(z;a,b)}}&=\left(1-\frac{az}{1+az}-\frac{\frac{bz}{1-bz}}{1+\frac{bz}{1-bz}}\right)^{-1}\\
&\color{blue}{=\left(1-\frac{az}{1+az}-bz\right)^{-1}}
\end{align*}
The wanted number $A_{10}$ we are looking for is $[z^{10}]$, the coefficient of $z^{10}$ of $A(z;1,1)$.

We obtain
\begin{align*}
{\color{blue}{A_{10}}}&=[z^{10}]A(z;1,1)\\
&=[z^{10}]\left(1-\frac{z}{1+z}-z\right)^{-1}\\
&=[z^{10}]\frac{1+z}{1-z-z^2}\tag{2}\\
&=\left([z^{11}]+[z^{10}]\right)\frac{z}{1-z-z^2}\tag{3}\\
&=F_{11}+F_{10}\\
&=98+55\\
&\color{blue}{=144}
\end{align*}
according to the claim.

Comment:

In (2) we use $[z^{10}](1+z)f(z)=\left([z^{10}]+[z^{10}]z\right)f(z)=\left([z^{11}]+[z^{10}]\right)zf(z)$.

In (3) we realise that we have derived the generating function
\begin{align*}
F(z)=\frac{z}{1-z-z^2}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}F_nz^n
\end{align*}
of the Fibonacci numbers.


